# neovim lsp client jump to implementation in another project

Tags: neovim, lsp

**Nvim info**

> NVIM v0.5.1
>
> Build type: Release
>
> LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Also using [*nvim-lspconfig*](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig), and [tsserver](https://github.com/theia-ide/typescript-language-server)

---

**Filesystem dir structure**

```
|--home
  |--project-A
    |--src
      |-- 
        |--/* Implementation somewhere here */
  |--project-B
    |--src
      |--
        |-- /* Used somewhere here */
```

I want to jump to the implementation in *project-A*, whereas it is used in *project-B*.

---

**Tried**

I am able to jump to other implementations within *project-B*, so my lsp client is functioning correctly.

To achieve the desired goto implementation, I added in workspace `/absolute-path-to/project-A` using the command
`lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()`, and then tried jumping to the implementation again but this did not work.

Output of ex command `lua print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))`:

> { "/absolute-path-to/project-A", "/absolute-path-to/project-B", "/absolute-path-to/project-A", "/absolute-path-to/project-B" }

For some reason paths repeat in the above output.

---

**Question**

Is there a way I can configure nvim LSP client so that a jump to implementation from *project-B* to *project-A* is possible?

Comment: do you try to use `bear -- make` to generate `compile_commands.json`?

Comment: i think you can add project-A by `:lua vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder()`